# Bootstrap Left and Right sidebar issues

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sidebar

I'm trying to create a page with the following features:

1. There is a left sidebar. This sidebar can be toggled open or closed with a button.
2. There is a right sidebar. This sidebar can be toggled open or closed with a button.
3. There is a main content area. When one or more sidebars is hidden, the main content area expands to fill the void. When both sidebars are open, it looks something like this:

```
----------------------------------------------------
|   Sidebar-Left  |  Content      |  Sidebar-right |
----------------------------------------------------
```

- As an extra wrinkle, the main content area actually consists of 3 columns - Left, Main, Right. When either or both sidebars is shown, the Left and Right content areas are hidden and the Main content area expands to fill the void. The Content column, therefore looks something like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------
|   Left-Content  |  Main-Content      |  Right-Content |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

- Finally, the open/close buttons would be pulled-left and pulled-right in a navbar above the whole thing and it would be a fluid container - with no padding between the columns.

No matter what I do - I can't get it to anything close to working.

A skeleton is [bootyply](http://www.bootply.com/S2aJL6cWov#) or [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skavan/y21Lg569/)

Comment: Not to sure if it's just me, but I cannot access your bootply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

## **[LIVE_DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/1nxToplVw6)**

CSS:

```
    div {
        border:2px solid;
    }
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div id="DivLeft" class="col-md-3">
            left Side bar
        </div>
        <div id="DivMain" class="col-md-6">
            <div id="DivLeftContent" class="col-md-4">
                Left Content
            </div>
            <div id="DivMainContent" class="col-md-4">
                Main Content
            </div>
            <div id="DivRightContent" class="col-md-4">
                Right Content
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="DivRight" class="col-md-3 ">
           right Side bar 
        </div>
    </div>
```

SCRIPT:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            MainDiv();
        });

        var right = 0, left = 0;
        $("#BtnRight").click(function () {
            if (right == 0) {
                $("#DivRight").hide();
                right = 1;
                if (left == 0) {
                    $("#DivMain").removeClass().addClass("col-md-9");
                } else {
                    $("#DivMain").removeClass().addClass("col-md-12");
                }
            } else {
                $("#DivRight").show();
                right = 0;
                if (left == 0) {
                    $("#DivMain").removeClass().addClass("col-md-6");
                } else {
                    $("#DivMain").removeClass().addClass("col-md-9");
                }
            }
            MainDiv();
        });
        $("#BtnLeft").click(function () {
            if (left == 0) {
                $("#DivLeft").hide();
                left = 1;
                if (right == 0) {
                    $("#DivMain").removeClass().addClass("col-md-9");
                } else {
                    $("#DivMain").removeClass().addClass("col-md-12");
                }
            } else {
                $("#DivLeft").show();
                left = 0;
                if (right == 0) {
                    $("#DivMain").removeClass().addClass("col-md-6");
                } else {
                    $("#DivMain").removeClass().addClass("col-md-9");
                }
            }
            MainDiv();
        });

        function MainDiv() {
            if (left == 1 && right == 1) {
                $("#DivLeftContent,#DivRightContent").hide();
                $("#DivMainContent").removeClass().addClass("col-md-12");
            } else {
                $("#DivLeftContent,#DivRightContent").show();
                $("#DivMainContent").removeClass().addClass("col-md-4");
            }
        }
```

Comment: That is ridiculously impressive! There I was faffing around with trying to get it all done in BootStrap row behaviour...and boom...just a few lines of jscript! I edited the jscript below to get exactly what I was looking for...

Comment: a follow on question:  
if the target div has more than one class, is there a way to remove a class that fits a pattern and then add a replacement class?  i.e.    ``$("#DivMainContent").removeClass("col-md-[wildcard]").addClass("col-md-12");

Comment: Yes this is the good idea, for acheiveing your requirement only i did like this

Answer (score 0):

@Jake745, awesome approach. Thanks. just a couple of changes to the MainDiv function to get the exact behaviour I was looking for:

```
function MainDiv() {
        if (left == 1 && right == 1) {
            $("#DivLeftContent,#DivRightContent").show();
            $("#DivMainContent").removeClass().addClass("col-md-4");
        } else {
            $("#DivLeftContent,#DivRightContent").hide();
            $("#DivMainContent").removeClass().addClass("col-md-12");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok sakvan i ll change my code :) If your issue solved means please tick my answer